Ubuntu 24.04 - Keyboard FR not reconize in log menu
I'm so happy to ask this one.
When i'm logging with my ubuntu 24.04, my keyboard layout is not recognized.
I have to write in qwerty my password. As soon as I'm logged, my keyboard layout is recognized and i can use my fr keyboard without any troubles.
The question is, where should I ask this question ?
I'm not so sure this is a "true" bug, but if so, I would be very happy to open an "official" issue on github or something like this...
Thx
